# What constitutes the condition "a server is up"

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm looking for verification on the following:

In order to find out whether a server is up, I'm supposed to 
establish a TCP connection to the host:port combination of the server given to me. 
And in that case, "*if a connection is established, then the service is up, otherwise - 
if the connection is refused, the service is down*".

So, should i be satisfied that the server is up when `getRemoteSocketAddress()` of [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) returns an object and not null? That is, does the following code always print the accurate info to the console?

```
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
    System.out.println("To console: The server is " + (clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress()==null?"down.":"up.")  );
```

To me, it does. However, i haven't practical info on these things and won't make sure without a second opinion.

Note: I'm aware that, the server being up doesn't necessarily mean that it is accepting and processing requests. That goes by exchanging some greetings to see/hear one another on who's who and go from there based on the protocol in between. However, these aren't relevant on this one.

TIA

Comment: If it is an HTTP server, I would `HEAD` for `http://server/` (i.e. for `/` path).

Comment: `socket.isConnected()` to see if it successfully connected. `socket.isClosed()` to see when it has been closed after already connecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establishing TCP connection is a health-check at level 3 (OSI). It tells you that the service is up and running and listening on the port. However, it doesnt tells you anything about upper layers. For instance, if you use the server to serve http objects, you could do with http `GET /sample.file` on top of the established tcp connection. Alternatively, you could use this server for REST API, and then not only would you like to see `200 OK` response from http layer, but maybe something more sophisticated in the response body.

Answer (score 1):

You would not even need to call

```
clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```

because the constructor call from:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
```

will try to connect to the socket and will throw an IOException if it fails to do so. So I would rather do this:

```
public boolean hostUp(String hostName, int port) {
    try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
        return true;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.